# Von Neumann Algebra of an Infinite Group

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the additive group of the integers. What is the Von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Let $M$ be the Von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I know that we have $M \subset B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}))$. But what are the linear maps in $M$ here?

According to the definition of a Von Neumann algebra, we have that if $a \in M$, then $a^* \in M$, $M = M''$.

But I don't really see what the Von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$ is like.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Gamma$ is a discrete group (in your case $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}$), you can consider the injective $*$-homomorphism
$$\lambda: \mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\to B(\ell^2(\Gamma))$$
defined by $\lambda(s)\delta_t = \delta_{st}$ for $s,t \in \Gamma$. Then the von Neumann algebra of $\Gamma$ is exactly the set
$$L(\Gamma):= \lambda(\mathbb{C}[\Gamma])'' \subseteq B(\ell^2(\Gamma)).$$

In your case, $\lambda(m)\delta_n = \delta_{m+n}$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Here is an explicit description of $M$ which does not refer to the representation $\lambda$. They are the operators that are "constant down the diagonals" (think of $\ell^2$-operators as infinite matrices to see where the terminology comes from):
$$L(\Gamma) = \{T \in B(\ell^2(\Gamma))\mid \forall s,t,x,y \in \Gamma: (ts^{-1} = yx^{-1}\implies \langle T\delta_s, \delta_t\rangle = \langle T \delta_x, \delta_y\rangle)\}$$

You can find all this stuff on p43-44 of the book "$C^*$-algebras and finite-dimensional approximations" by Brown and Ozawa.

Comment: It might be interesting to add that $L(\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to $L^\infty(S^1)$, represented as multiplication operators on $L^2(S^1)$, via the Fourier transform.

Comment: Just some questions on the notations. What is $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$? And what is $\delta_t$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ is the complex group algebra associated to $\Gamma$: thus the free vector space with basis $\Gamma$ with multiplication defined by the group multiplication and extended linearly. $\delta_t$ is the characteristic function of $\ell^2(\Gamma)$  that is $1$ in $t\in \Gamma$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: I gave a reference for that. It is a consequence of the bicommutant theorem.