# Group Von Neumann Algebra Application

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

This is a follow up question on [Von Neumann Algebra of an Infinite Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088386/von-neumann-algebra-of-an-infinite-group/4088394#4088394).

> Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the additive group of the integers. What is the Von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$?
> Let $M$ be the Von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$.
> I know that we have $M \subset B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}))$. But what are the linear maps in $M$ here?

> If $\Gamma$ is a discrete group (in your case $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}$), you can consider the injective $*$-homomorphism
> $$\lambda: \mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\to B(\ell^2(\Gamma))$$
> defined by $\lambda(s)\delta_t = \delta_{st}$ for $s,t \in \Gamma$. Then the von Neumann algebra of $\Gamma$ is exactly the set
> $$L(\Gamma):= \lambda(\mathbb{C}[\Gamma])'' \subseteq B(\ell^2(\Gamma)).$$
> In your case, $\lambda(m)\delta_n = \delta_{m+n}$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Following on QuantumSpace's answer, since we are working with additive groups we have $\lambda(k)= \lambda(1)^k$.

My question is: what is $\lambda(1) $ here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for, since what $\lambda(1)$ is appears already in the text you quoted. You have
$$
\lambda(1)\delta_n=\delta_{n+1}. 
$$
That is, $\lambda(1)$ is the bilateral shift corresponding to the canonical basis.

Comment: Since we are in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, isn't $\lambda(1)$ a bilateral shift?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. In my mind, I alwasy see $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for :D